# How to send audio through spring rest controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, audio

I'd like to send mp3 file via RestContoller and then receive it in Angular  - eventually in html audio tag. It's not about streaming it live. I just want to send an Ajax request form Angular, and get mp3 file, or list of mp3 files. My question concerns strictly backend, but I'll also appreciate if someone tells me hot to do use it in Angular frontend.

Comment: Share related code which you have tried

Comment: I tried to use  Spring Content, but somehow I can't POST any new files. When I do POST I recieve "cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its last-modified timestamp". Here is my code snippet: https://pastebin.com/TDHNqq8B

Comment: Resolved: There was a bug in old version of Spring Content - all it needed was to update dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send the mp3 file itself, but you can send a link to the mp3 resource instead, using Spring's hypermedia-driven REST support. A fairly simple tutorial is available on their site:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/